# User control inside ag-grid cell

Tags: angular, editor, multi-select, ag-grid

Ho do I put a user control inside an ag-grid cell editor?

Column Definition :

```
 {
            headerName: 'Product',
            field: 'product',
            width: 140,
            editable: true,
            cellRendererFramework: ProductEditorComponent
        },
```

and the editor component :

```
@Component({
selector: 'ag-product-editor-control',
template: ` 
    <div #container>       
      <ng-select
            [options]="products"
            [multiple]="true"
            placeholder="Select multiple">
        </ng-select>
    </div>
`,
providers: [RegionProductsConfigService]

})
  export class ProductEditorComponent implements AgEditorComponent, AfterViewInit {
products: Array<any>;
item: any;

@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) private container;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.container.element.nativeElement.focus();
}  

agInit(params : any): void {
  this.products = RegionProductsConfigService.getProducts().map(x => ({ 'value': x.ID, 'label': x.Name }));
}
}
```

But it doesnt seem to bind items. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to raise a custom event in the cell renderer component which contains a reference to the row in the grid and the selected value. I could then add add an event listener in the parent component which updated the grid's rowData attribute.

The cell renderer should look something like this:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {AgRendererComponent} from "ag-grid-ng2";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: `<md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="onChange($event)">
                  <md-option 
                      ngfor="let opt of params.context['options']" 
                      value="{{ opt.value }}">
                      {{ opt.name }}
                  </md-option>
               </md-select>`
})

export class CustomCellRendererComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
    private params: any;
    private selectedValue: string;

    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;
        this.selectedValue = this.params['data']['selectedValue'];
    }

    onChange(event: any) {
        let gridEvent: CustomEvent = new CustomEvent('option-changed', {
            'bubbles': true,
            'detail': {
                'row': this.params.data.row,
                'value': event.value
            }
        });
        event.source.trigger.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(gridEvent);
    }
}
```

Back in the parent component, the event listener looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('option-changed', (e) => {
    this.rowData[e['detail']['row']].colName = e['detail']['value'];
});
```

There is a slightly longer example with contextual detail on my blog at [velociter.blogspot.co.uk](http://velociter.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/using-custom-input-widget-in-ag-grid.html)

Hope this helps!